# How to adjust css print and apply page break for every tab in window.print?

Tags: html, css

I have tab full of form, I want to print all the form information. I have prepared the download button in the tab form. Its working well but I want adjust the CSS for the print. I want to make it more nicer but I can't figured it out how in the CSS part. I want to achieve output that 1 tab for one page. its that possible to do that ?

Each of the menu/tab have different page.

If I want to achieve that how do I adjust the CSS and give it some padding ?

```js
$("#downloadPdf").click(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .tab-content>.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  #downloadPdf {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homepage">Terms & Condition</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Form</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#form">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="homepage" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
        <span style="font-size: 80%;"><i>Please read the terms and condition first</i></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="reg"> Please tick this if u have read and understand everything </p>
      </div>
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="info" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <p><button type="button" id="downloadPdf" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download">Download</button></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution you need *css* property `page-break-before: always;`  and set it for 2, 3, 4 tab.

**CSS**

```css
@media print {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .tab-content > .fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  #downloadPdf {
    display: none;
  }
  /* New lines */
  #home,
  #info,
  #form {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

```js
$('#downloadPdf').click(function () {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .tab-content>.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  #downloadPdf {
    display: none;
  }
  /* New lines */
  #home,
  #info,
  #form {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#homepage">Terms & Condition</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Info</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Form</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#form">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="homepage" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
      <span style="font-size: 80%"><i>Please read the terms and condition first</i></span
          >
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="reg" /> Please tick this if u have read
            and understand everything
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <p>
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="info" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 3</h3>
          <p>
            Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto
            beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
          </p>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <p>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="downloadPdf"
          class="btn btn-warning"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          data-placement="top"
          title="Download"
        >
          Download
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
```